# How to validate the input boxes in multi-tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate and [jquery tabs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) to create a multi-tabs form

Assume a simple form :

> tab 1 for enter address, tab 2 for enter name, tab 3 for submit

html

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">address</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile">name</a></li>
  <li><a href="#submit">submit</a></li>
</ul>

 <form id="selectList" method="post" action="finish.php">
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">//input box address</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">//input box name</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">//submit button</div>
</div>
 </form>
```

js validate

```
  $("#selectList").validate( {
      rules: {
         "selectList[]": {
              required: true,
              minlength: 1
          }
       }
   })

});
```

The problems are:

1. As you can see , although all the tabs is inside the form, however, if the submit button is in the tab 3, it can not  validate the input box in tab 1, 2, How can i specific the validation rule for different tabs?

Thank you

**Updated:**

```
$("#optionalform").validate({
    ignore:''
});
```

Using this  standalone can help doing this, the problem is , i can not set rules, and the data selector plugin and other function in a tab not working, it probably skip all my element?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.tabbable').tabs();
$("#selectList").validate({
    ignore:''

        rules: {
         "selectList[]": {
              required: true,
              minlength: 1
          }
       }
   })
          $('#dd').datebox({  
    required:true  
});



});


$(function(){
  $("#closeTab").click(function() {
             window.parent.$('#tt').tabs('close','Add Campaign'); 
             location.reload();     
  });
});
```

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to follow good practice with indentation and spacing but you have something very wrong with your syntax.  You're missing a comma `,` after `ignore:''`.  Although I'm not sure what you think you're achieving with an empty parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to call the validation for each time a tab is changed.

```
$('.selector').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) { ... } //run validation here?
});
```

Comment: Not really understand how to implment, would you mind provide a simple example?

Comment: actually i got something but it has some flaw

Comment: Thanks although your answer not what i final got